# Filtering collection by system:index using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to filter a Sentinel-2 collection by the `system:index` property. I have selected three specific tiles identified by its respective id, then tried filtering them from a collection using `filter(ee.Filter.eq())` function, but it does not load any image. It works well for filtering only one image id, but is not working with several at the same time.

```
var tiles = [
  '20190129T160521_20190129T161214_T17RMN',
  '20190106T160511_20190106T160506_T17RNJ',
  '20190106T160511_20190106T160506_T17RNK'
]

var filtered = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', tiles))

print(filtered.size());
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/51da7be720dd9e67e9e32fa3c6fafb85?noload=true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the `ee.Filter.inList()` filter:

```
var tiles = [
  '20190129T160521_20190129T161214_T17RMN',
  '20190106T160511_20190106T160506_T17RNJ',
  '20190106T160511_20190106T160506_T17RNK'
]

var filtered = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('system:index', tiles))

print(filtered.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tiles = [
  '20190129T160521_20190129T161214_T17RMN',
  '20190106T160511_20190106T160506_T17RNJ',
  '20190106T160511_20190106T160506_T17RNK'
]

var filtered = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filter(ee.Filter.equals('system:index', tiles))

print(filtered.size());
```

Comment: use ee.Filter.equals() filter...it worked for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).